# Steam installation

Tags: software-installation, steam

I downloaded Steam from their site,got the steam launcher.deb file opened it with software installer and then this appears on my screen when i try to start steam.I`m using 16.04 LTS Gnome ubuntu

[image]

Comment: Remove it and install directly from the official repositories.

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: i used sudo apt-get remove steam

Comment: But it still exists on my PC

Answer (score 1):

I know its old but no answer exists so I recommend you try:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge steam
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install steam
```

This should auto install it from the official repo's and work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. yes. This problem has been a problem for many steam users on linux systems... This worked for me..

1. Make sure you are connected to the internet
2. then try `sudo apt-get update`
3. then `sudo apt-get install libc6-i386`

If that doesn't work, try:

```
find /lib -name libc.so.6
ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6
mkdir ~/steamcmd2 && cd $_
wget http://media.steampowered.com/client/steamcmd_linux.tar.gz
tar -xvzf steamcmd_linux.tar.gz
./steamcmd.sh
```

Then type in `./steam.sh`

that worked for me, i hope it helped you.

P.S. I'm running Linux Ubuntu MATE 16.4